# Displaying related posts by tags on category template page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nested-loops

I would like to display related posts by tags next to posts on category page. 
All related posts pieces of code I could find are to be used in nested loops on `single.php` but I need it to be in the loop on category page.

So when you go to category "Cats" it should output the following:
"Post 1 title", category "Cats", tag "Kittens"
"Related post 1.1 title", tag "Kittens"
"Related post 1.2 title", tag "Kittens"

---

"Post 2 title", category "Cats", tag "tomcats"
"Related post 2.1 title", tag "tomcats"
"Related post 2.2 title", tag "tomcats"

---

...

This is the code I came up with, but it breaks.

`// First query
    $my_query = new WP_Query('cat=6');

```
// If first query have posts
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) :

    // While first query have posts
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
    ?>

    <!-- start post -->


     <!-- End post div -->

        <?php
        // tags

            $tag_ids = array();
                            foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
                            $args=array(
                            'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                            'posts_per_page'=>99,
                            'caller_get_posts'=>1
                            );
            // Second query
            $my_second_query = new WP_Query('$args');

            // If second query have posts
            if( $my_second_query->have_posts() ) :
            ?>

                <?php
                // While second query have posts
                while( $my_second_query->have_posts() ) : $my_second_query->the_post();


                    ?>
                    <!-- start post -->


     <!-- End post div -->


                    <?php
                // End second while have posts
                endwhile;
                ?>
    <?php
    // End first while have posts
    endwhile; 

// End if first query have posts
endif;
?>`
```

Is this even possible? I couldn't for the life of me find example.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's possible. Looks like you were in the right direction with your code. All you need to do is create a custom query that looks at the current post's tags and then uses those to find other posts. It really doesn't matter if it's used in `single.php` or anywhere else, as long as you are in the loop. Add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
function echo_related_posts() {
    global $post;
    // Get the current post's tags
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID );
    $tagIDs = array();
    if ( $tags ) {
        // Fill an array with the current post's tag ids
        $tagcount = count( $tags );
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $tagcount; $i++ ) {
            $tagIDs[$i] = $tags[$i]->term_id;
        }
        // Query options, the magic is with 'tag__in'
        $args = array(
            'tag__in' => $tagIDs,
            'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
            'showposts'=> 5
        );
        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        // If we have related posts, show them
        if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $related = '';
            while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                $my_query->the_post();
                $current = $my_query->current_post + 1;
                $related .= "Related post " . $current . ": ";
                $related .= "<a href='" . get_permalink() . "' >";
                $related .= get_the_title();
                $related .= "</a>";
                if ( ( $my_query->current_post + 1 ) != ( $my_query->post_count ) ) $related .= ", ";
            }
            echo $related;
        }
        else echo "No related posts";
    }
    else echo "No related posts";
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Obviously you can change anything in this function to get the exact results you are looking for, it's just an example that will echo up to five related posts. Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query for further reference on custom queries.

With that function in place, you now have access to the `echo_related_posts()` function, which will output any related posts by common tags. So in your `category.php` or whichever template is being used for your categories page, you can do something like the following (this is an over-simplified loop for brevity, just note the `echo_related_posts()` function):

```
// Inside your existing loop
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    // Output the current post info here

    // Output the related posts
    <?php echo_related_posts(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Assuming related posts are found, it will output something like this:

"Related post 1: Title One, Related post 2: Title Two, Related post 3: Title Three"

Hopefully you can take it from there!

Comment: Thank you sooo much, I just got back from my vacation and will continue on this project and get back to you with results!